# Resetting column based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to reset Batting Order so when inning = 0, batting order restarts at one, need to do this because my original formula did not account for opponent being the same

Here is my formula so far...

```
    df['Batting Order'] = df.groupby('opponent'['pa'].cumsum().mod(9).apply(lambda x: 9 if x == 0 else x)      
Input
      pa  Batting Order  inning opponent
2666   1              8      15   Toledo
2667   1              9      16   Toledo
2668   1              1      17   Toledo
2669   0              1      17   Toledo
2670   1              2      17   Toledo
2671   1              3      18   Toledo
2672   1              4      19   Toledo
2673   1              5      19   Toledo
2674   1              6      20   Toledo
2675   1              7       0   Toledo
2676   1              8       1   Toledo
2677   1              9       1   Toledo
2678   0              9       1   Toledo
2679   1              1       1   Toledo
2680   1              2       1   Toledo
2681   0              2       1   Toledo
2682   0              2       1   Toledo
2683   0              2       1   Toledo
2684   1              3       1   Toledo
2685   1              4       2   Toledo
2686   1              5       3   Toledo
2687   1              6       4   Toledo
2688   1              7       5   Toledo
2689   1              8       6   Toledo
```

This is the output that I want:

```
Output
      pa  Batting Order  inning opponent
2666   1              8      15   Toledo
2667   1              9      16   Toledo
2668   1              1      17   Toledo
2669   0              1      17   Toledo
2670   1              2      17   Toledo
2671   1              3      18   Toledo
2672   1              4      19   Toledo
2673   1              5      19   Toledo
2674   1              6      20   Toledo
2675   1              1       0   Toledo
2676   1              2       1   Toledo
2677   1              3       1   Toledo
2678   0              3       1   Toledo
2679   1              4       1   Toledo
2680   1              5       1   Toledo
2681   0              5       1   Toledo
2682   0              5       1   Toledo
2683   0              5       1   Toledo
2684   1              6       1   Toledo
2685   1              7       2   Toledo
2686   1              8       3   Toledo
2687   1              9       4   Toledo
2688   1              1       5   Toledo
2689   1              2       6   Toledo
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['pa'].eq(0),'Batting Order']=1`?

Comment: please show an example of yours inpu and output dataframe